# What technology or method is used for the making of "Chicken Run"?

Tags: film-techniques, animation, chicken-run

I have seen this animated movie called  [**Chicken Run**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rUSoF2nwPw8)

It seems like some form of **clay puppets** are used in this movie.

So my question is:

**What technology is used in this movie? Is it pure animation or were actual clay models used while filming this movie?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chicken Run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_Run) is a true clay model [stop-motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_motion) animation; made by [Aardman Animations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aardman_Animations).

They came from almost nowhere [they had history but weren't well-known in their own right*] with a series of adverts for UK television, extolling the benefits of gas central heating. Each advert featured a vox pop of a real interview, with an clay stop-mo animal taking the visual part.
This was eventually turned into a show in its own right, called [Creature Comforts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_Comforts), which won an Oscar.

They then made the short film starring [Wallace & Gromit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_and_Gromit), A Grand Day Out, which failed to win the oscar because it was beaten by Creature Comforts, followed by two more shorts, The Wrong Trousers & A Close Shave. Then they moved to a full-length feature, The Curse of the Were-Rabbit. All three were Oscar-winners.

*Their most famous earlier contributions were for the BBC TV show Vision On & the video for Peter Gabriel's [Sledgehammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g93mz_eZ5N4), where they also stop-mo'd Gabriel as well as the backgrounds.

Comment: I am not sure that a would call honing their skills since the 1970s coming from almost nowhere.

Comment: They were known in the industry, but were very *niche*. Until they made their own name famous, not many people wanted stop-mo plasticine animations. They single-handedly changed that; with a lucky start from British Gas.

Comment: They were  well known in the UK amongst the public any one who grew up watching Morph on Tony Harts show were aware of them, but it's a matter of personal perception. Being niche is not the same as being Unknown.